# Using Open Trip Planner

Tags: opentripplanner

I can't find any information about how to use the analyst functionality of Open Trip Planner. The official resources only go on about point-sets and not how to use the framework.

I also looked here: https://opentripplanner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Analyst/#pointsets 
, but it says this documentation is deprecated.

Could someone help me to get the analyst api running?

Comment: The documentation is confusing me as well, especially because i know otp analysis function as an isochrones generator. Can you explain in your own words what your final result should be or look like?

Answer (score 1):

The API docs for OTP are here:

http://dev.opentripplanner.org/apidoc/1.4.0/

I don't see a specific "Analyst" API, but some of the REST endpoints have "analyst" in the name. Can you find the functionality you want in that API doc?